# MS Access Linked Tables to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have looked into "How to get MS Access Linked Tables to SQL Server", however, I didn't find any results that applied to my situation.

I am upgrading a database(`db1`) from MS Access to SQL Server. I'm needing to get the linked tables from `db1` into SQL Server(2016).

Is there somehow a way to move the linked table connection to my SQL Server? The linked tables I currently have are from one Access database to another Access database.

Note: The linked tables in `db1` are to another MS Access (2007) database.

Comment: I have read this three or four times and it just doesn't make any sense. Linked tables in Access are NOT in Access. They are a remote table somewhere, in your case probably on your sql server. You need to explain more clearly what the issue is here.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to take your tables that currently reside in Access and create them in your sql server database?

Comment: Check out SSMA for Access https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SeanLange I have two MS Access databases (`db1` , `db2`). Linked tables in `db1` point to tables in `db2`. I am moving `db1` to SQL Server and am needing to somehow move these linked tables as well. They currently are not touching SQL Server. (I'm very new to SQL Server and databases in general. So I apologize for my noob questions)

Comment: So the table is still in Access? You need to create a linked server in sql server. You can read about them here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017 And for details on creating one....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: BTW not my downvote but I am sure it is because this isn't very clear.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for your input and comments! I will look into your `Linked Servers` and see if this will work for me. Note: I have attempted to clarify the post with an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access "links" SQL Server tables by opening a connection to SQL Server and performing whatever tasks it needs to, like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.

If you're talking about going the other way, there is no "reverse" functionality where SQL Server will open up an Access database to perform queries.

If you just need to import the data from Access to SQL Server, right click on your database and select Tasks, then select "Import Data".

Edit: Creating a linked server on SQL with Access apparently is possible, however given that Access locking isn't designed for any significant amount of concurrency, I'd still recommend against it, unless this is just a one time thing.

Comment: Sure there is. Sql Server has Linked Servers which can connect to just about any data source.

Comment: I have gone through that process (`Tasks > Import Data`) and have gotten to where I am now. Though, thank you for the input! `db2` is still in production and being used so its data is constantly updating.

Comment: What's the actual problem? If it's data consistency, you're going to have to turn off whatever is feeding it for a little while to do the cut-over.

Comment: Data consistency is definitely important. `db2` is widely used and handles a lot of traffic internally. I was really looking for something like Access's linked table to another Access database. The difference being Access to SQL Server.

Comment: You can link it. but you can't use it for high volume production. Access has terrible locking and performance issues on multi-user systems. At some point, Access is going to have to go away.

Comment: @TerryCarmen I couldn't agree more. We are currently in the process of moving away from Access. However, the majority of our databases are Access-based. What I am currently moving over is just the first thing being attempted. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Good luck with it. I just finished up a 4+ year project doing that. Wait until you start porting over the queries. Access syntax is "special" 8-) OTOH, when you're done, you'll both be an expert, and never want to see it again. 8-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably have your work cut out for you.  If your Access DB isn't too complex, the Upsize wizard may do some of the work for you.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-access-data-to-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-upsizing-wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924

However, if your DB is somewhat complex, and I'm guessing it is, the Upsize wizard won't help much.  The Wizard definitely won't handle the Forms and Reports; those are very specific to Access.  The SQL will be different, but probably only slightly different.  There are probably a bunch of ways to approach this.  One that comes to mind is the possibility of exporting all tables in Access, as CSV files, and then bulk loading those CSV files into SQL Server.  That, at least, would get the data loaded into the schema.  Then you can start rebuilding the queries.  Well, just do one step at a time.

```
'    VBA to run in Access
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
Set dbs = Application.CurrentData
For Each obj In dbs.AllTables
If Left(obj.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , obj.Name, obj.Name & ".csv", True
'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, obj.Name, obj.Name & ".xls", True
End If
Next obj

End Sub
```

That should get you going, I think.  Post back if you have additional questions or need some additional clarity about this concept.  Again, there are probably may approaches to this issue.  This is just one thing that comes to mind.

Comment: What I ended up going with is finding the source of the Linked Tables and importing those individually from a different Access Database upon a button press.